# Npm run preview with vite react app works but I can't deploy it to netlify

Tags: typescript, npm, vite, netlify, chakra-ui

I've built an app that I'd like to deploy to netlify but it won't work. The app is a react vite app using typescript and chakra-ui. The build is succesful but I get a lot pf these errors:
**'node_modules/@chakra-ui/button/dist/chunk-DA7QIPTJ.mjs (1:0) Module level directives cause errors when bundled, "use client" in "node_modules/@chakra-ui/button/dist/chunk-DA7QIPTJ.mjs" was ignored.'**

It works fine when I run it locally with 'npm run dev' and also after the build with 'npm run preview' but I get the errors shown in the image after I deploy it to netlify.

[The error I'm getting on the netlify page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVEnD.png)

Can someone please help?

I've also tried deploying it to github pages and vercel but the same thing happens there.

Comment: When you do a `npm run build` you should produce a dist folder. Look at the index.html <head> and in the assets folder. Does your application work and just some scripts / assets are missing?

Comment: Here is my index.html in the dist folder: https://imgur.com/a/XwqRdy7

Is there something missing that should be included after I run 'npm run build'? This is my first time trying to deploy a react vite app.

Comment: Your asset urls look wrong. But its hard to tell just looking at the index.html. 
Your URLs include the a folder called "game-discovery" is this folder present in the dist folder with the assets underneath it?

Comment: Yes I agree, I've tried changing the url's in index.html but then the app stops working when I do 'npm run preview', here is my file structure for the project: https://imgur.com/a/c9BG7qg 
Here is my repository on github: https://github.com/FelixGustafsson/game-discovery

There is no game-discovery folder underneath my dist folder no but that's the name of the main folder.

PS. I really appreciate you helping me!

Comment: Ah the repository helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the base in your vite config. Which you can use to define a prefix for all your assets. Once you remove it your linked assets in your `html` file should work.

1. Remove `base` in your vite config

```
  base: "/game-discovery/",
```

2. `npm run build`
3. Success :D

Comment: Thank you this worked! I read the vite docs for deploying to netlify and probably misunderstood what they said about the vite config file and base.

Comment: glad I could help :)